# location of FND_FILE log file

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracleapplications

I  create a log file in my procedure:

```
v_log_file        VARCHAR2 (250) := FND_FILE.LOG;
```

and during my procedure I write in this file :

```
FND_FILE.PUT_LINE (
               v_log_file,
               '### start');
```

How can I see my log file to check if it's written correctly? Where can I find my log file?

Comment: FND_FILE is an Oracle EBS artifact. It's got nothing to do with SQL Developer.

Comment: you can only check that, when you create a concurrent program associated with a PLSQL executable and then run the program :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE instead to view it in SQL developer. Use the below code before compiling your anonymous block.

```
   SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
```